# What's the folder structure standard for iOS frameworks?

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks

I can only find the document for Mac frameworks: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html

Is there a similar doc for iOS?
What are the differences between Mac & iOS frameworks? (One of the differences I notice is the path of the Info.plist file.)

Answer (score 1):

Found it:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle

macOS, iOS, tvOS... This Document has it all.